# Tomcat 7 - Maven Plugin not working why?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, tomcat7

When trying to use automatic deployment in tomcat, I get the following error

> The project com.tradair.tnet:tnet:1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   (c:\tradair\sources\java\pom.xml) has 1 error
>   'dependencies.dependency.version' for
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:jar must be a valid
>   version but is '${mavenVersion}'. @ line 229, column 16

How do I fix this  `org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:jar`  issue?

Answer (score 1):

Maven is telling your that the `version` part is missing.  What version of the plugin do you wish to use?  Specify it.  Something like:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>                       <<< Some version number
  <executions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've declared your plugin dependency as follows:

```
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
```

Have you set a value for the property **mavenVersion**?